# Get an error when call class in another class (not in method or function)

Tags: c#

I made two class 
first Input.cs

```
public class Input
{


}
```

I tried to call input class in inputsevice.cs

second inputsevice.cs

```
public class InputService
{
    Input test= new Input();
    test// error (I can't use this field)
}
```

I can't find input field i got {input is a field but use like type}

Comment: You need to use it inside a method or a function, etc.

Comment: Well, technically this is actually a well-formed question. He showed the relative code and the error. It just looks bad because this is a day-one mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use it

```
//Class should have certain publicly accessible properties or methods to access from other classes.
    public class Input
    {
        private int x = 5;
        public string MyInput {get; set;} //Publicly accessible property
        public void DisplayInput()  //Publicly accessible method
        {
             Console.WriteLine(MyInput);
             Console.WriteLine(x);
        } 
    }        
    
    
    public class InputService
    {
        Input test= new Input(); //Object initialization
    
        InputService()   //Constructor
        { 
            //Properties and methods can be accessed in methods. 
            test.MyInput = "Hello World!";  
            //test.x   you can't access x because it is private.
            test.DisplayInput();

        }
        
    }
```

> **Output:**
>
> Hello World!
>
> 5

Comment: Thank you so much for your expalaination I really love it

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should accept this as an answer. [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything with a property in a member declaration statement (it doesn't make sense to do so).  But you can access it in any method of the class:

```
public class Input
{
    public int name { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // you can access "name" here
    }
}
```

Comment: I call input class in inputService class
but the result is error
class input{

}
class input service{
input test = new input();
test // i try to use test field but is error
}

Comment: @Karim: Can you describe the problem more effectively in your question, including the actual code you're using and the error you're receiving?  Currently your question only indicates that you're trying to access a property outside the context of a method, which isn't semantically valid.

Comment: @Karim: Ok, you've edited the question, but it's still the same question and this answer still applies.